# Receive response as XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

When a user clicks a button, i need to run a Database query to receive the database response as XML. I am newbie, and i was unable to find any tutorials. This might be because i have no clue how to search for it. Can someone point me to a tutorial that describes how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the 'For XML' keyword(s) there are a couple of ways to shape the data but the MSDN link below is a good start

[MSDN FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178107.aspx)